# how to correctly use a dynamically allocated array as a (bi)(nth)dimentional one?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, malloc

If I allocate memory with malloc I get a contiguous chunk of memory:

```
typedef struct s_point
{
    float   x;
    float   y;
    float   z;
    float   w;
}   t_point;

t_point *matrix = malloc(sizeof(t_point) * (i * j));
```

But then how can I do something like:

```
matrix[x][y] = data;
```

On it? If it it is just a pointer and not a pointer pointer?

Comment: What _type_ are  `i,j`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica int why?

Comment: Note that `(i * j)` may overflow when `sizeof(t_point) * i * j` does not as the multiplication is done using `size_t` math instead of the `int` multiplication of `i*j`.  `size_t` math is typically wider, sometimes much wider than `int`.  Of course other code needs protection too.   Tip: Best to use `size_t` math for array indexing.  Take care, `size_t` is some _unsigned_ type.

Comment: If you have a pointer to a nth degree array like `t_point (*matrix)[dim1][dim2][dim3];` then fully allocate memory for it with `matrix = malloc(sizeof *malloc);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allocated a one dimensional array that simulates a two-dimensional array like

```
t_point *matrix = malloc(sizeof(t_point) * (m * n));
```

where `m` is the number of rows and `n` is the number of columns.
Then for two indices `i` and `j` you can write for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        matrix[i * n + j] = data;
    }
}
```

Actually it is the same if to write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < m * n; i++ )
{
    matrix[i] = data;
}
```

In the both cases the variable data must have the type `t_point`. Otherwise you need to assign each data member of objects separately as for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < m * n; i++ )
{
    matrix[i].x = x;
    matrix[i].y = y;
    matrix[i].z = z;
    matrix[i].w = w;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pointer to Variable Length Array:

```
t_point (*matrix)[n] = malloc(sizeof(t_point[m][n]));
```

It allocates a *contiguous* chunk of memory where individual elements are accessible via `matrix[i][j]`. Just remember to call `free(matrix)` when the memory is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Vlad's and tstanisl's answers are great.

Another way, that support matrix[x][y] syntax, doesn't use VLA and allocate just two continous chunks of memory:

```c
t_point* buf = malloc(sizeof(t_point) * rows * cols);
t_point** matrix = malloc(sizeof(t_point*) * rows);
for(unsigned i = 0; i<rows; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = buf + (i*cols);
}
// ...
free(buf);
free(matrix);
```

It also allows you to do tricks like swapping rows by just reassigning pointers (I don't know if that happens with  matrices, but it is sometimes handy with something like argv). If you don't need that, I would probably go for Vlad's method

Comment: I thought doing `for(unsigned i = 0; i<rows; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = buf + (i*cols);
}` wasn't possible but I guess it is just pointers

Comment: If you think that pointer arithmetic is  unintuitive, then another way is `matrix[i] = &buf[i*cols]`